# Dynamic Linq: Reference relationships that don't have foreign keys

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, dynamic-linq

I'm using the Dynamic Linq features described in:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

which works fine as long as I'm only refering objects where foreign keys are setup properly.

Is there any way to referense a Table where foreign keys aren't setup?

i.e. something like:

```
.Where("it.DeleteFlag == false && context.Tags(KeyId == it.Id)")
```

Comment: Does it allow you to do a join? Did you know you can setup psuedo- relationships in Linq2SQL?

Comment: Yes, it allows for example "it.Orders.Any(Ratings!=null && Ratings.Reported !=null && Ratings.Reported!=false)". I guess pseudo- relationship could be a useful trick!